# PubSub module returning error

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, ejabberd

I'm working on getting [Jappix](https://github.com/jappix/jappix) running. I'm using ejabberd as my XMPP server and I've got everything working except comments and viewing attachments - group chat, single chat, external authentication, private messages, friend lists, presence and other works as intended.

My configuration is the same as the one the Jappix project provides on their [jappix/jappix-tools](https://github.com/jappix/jappix-tools/blob/master/ejabberd/configs/config_ejabberd.cfg.txt) github repository. I have no errors in my ejabberd log, the only thing I got while debugging and digging everything up is that this is an example stanza sent to the server:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="get" id="get_31-30" to="pubsub.mydomain.com" xml:lang="en">
    <pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
        <items node="urn:xmpp:microblog:0:comments/3aca5f972fe7198805bdd1a20f502f35"/>
    </pubsub>
</iq>
```

And this is the response I get from the server:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="pubsub.mydomain.com" to="arqu@mydomain.com/jappix (1378149270017)" type="error" id="get_31-30" xml:lang="en" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
    <pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
        <items node="urn:xmpp:microblog:0:comments/3aca5f972fe7198805bdd1a20f502f35"/>
    </pubsub>
    <error code="503" type="cancel">
        <service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
    </error>
</iq>
```

And in Jappix I just get the usual "Service Unavailable" error message.

Additional info:
My BOSH is the internal one of ejabberd and works fine as far as i know, I've setup the reverse proxy and everything else to make it work. Still could be something related to this and not reaching the service on some other port maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you do not have pubsub enabled/installed on your server.

Have you tried any other pubsub request?

Comment: In the modules section of my configuration file and according to Jappix specification too I've loaded the pubsub module, and I do have other pubsub functionality, for example the geolocation works perfectly.

Comment: Here is an example: `<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="set"><pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"><publish node="http://jabber.org/protocol/geoloc"><item><geoloc xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/geoloc"><lat>43.9896631</lat><lon>18.1689166</lon><country>Bosnia and Herzegovina</country><countrycode>BA</countrycode><region>FBIH</region><locality>Vis</locality><street>R445</street><text>R445, Visoko, Bosnia and Herzegovina</text><uri>http://maps.google.com/?q=43.9952448,18.1713934</uri><timestamp>2013-09-05T21:22:57Z</timestamp></geoloc></item></publish></pubsub></iq>`

Comment: That is a PEP message (not addressed to pubsub.mydomain.com). I don't know if ejabberd uses the same module for pubsub and pep. Try sending that same stanza to the pubsub service and see what you get.

Comment: It turned out eJabberd doesn't fully support Jappix and thus doesn't work as expected. I'll accept this answer for now.